# VScode won't recognize syntax of a written code however it will recognize copy/pasted one

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

For some reason the code I'm writing in VScode giving me an error. However if I copy and paste exactly the same code from Github it works perfectly fine.
It really confuses me and I don't understand what is going on.
Also if you take a look at the image. For some reason VScode won't Syntax highlight Javascript identifier ($) from my code however it highlights copy/pasted one.
[image]

Comment: You're using the wrong quotes, replace the `'` with `.

Comment: "For some reason the code I'm writing in VScode giving me an error" — That's a linter warning.

Comment: You are using apostrophe `'` instead of backticks 

    `

backticks are used for string interpolation in JS : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: When you see something like this it's often best to see what the actual differences is. You assumed it's "exactly the same code" while a simple comparison would show that it is not, in fact, exactly the same. Little things mean a lot.